# jQuery Unwrap Selected Element

Tags: jquery

How can I remove an element from the DOM, but still keep its content?

I looked into .unwrap() but that seems to remove the parent of an element no mater what its id or class is.

I want to select any element in the DOM and remove it, but still keep its child elements. My structure is similar to this.

```
<div class="remove-1">
   <div class="remove-2">

      <span>keep<h1>all</h1>this</span>

   </div>
</div>
```

I would use this to remove the "remove-1" element

```
 $(".remove-2").unwrap(); // removes parent "remove-1".
```

But how would I then remove "remove-2" element since that span wont always be there and its parent could be a different element I don't want to remove?

Comment: You will have to detach and reattach the `div.remove-2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use function `.detach()` and when you will need to attach these elements back to DOM, then you will append to DOM tree.

See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/detach/

---

**Update 1:**

If you want to unwrap content of your element, then you need to select element children elements and unwrap them all.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $("#detach").children().unwrap();
});
```

```css
#detach {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}
span {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="detach">

  <span>KEEP</span>
  <span>Keep second</span>
</h1>

<button>Unwrap content of red element</button>
```

Comment: This removes all child elements I'm using it like this $("#remove-1").detach();

Comment: I'm also not looking to re-attach the element. I simply want to remove it but keep is content.

Comment: Maybe you can provide example what you have and what you want as result? Because now I can't understand what exactly you want: remove `.remove-1` but keep its content, or remove `.remove-2` and keep its content or something else?

Comment: see here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYOMRV I added detach to the h1 and its child span is removed, I want to keep the child span but remove "#detach"

Comment: @Shabbb Now I see what you want, you can select all children of your element and unwrap them: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ByzGyg